# Android libGDX moving object and detect

Tags: android, libgdx

I just started experimenting libgdx and understanding... I looked sample projects... My problem :

[image: i.hizliresim.com/e79AlN.png]

The 1 and 6 originial ball number. And other balls, the ball's(1 and 6) will go randomly other places. (speed 1). ex . If a i am torch on the any ball, its speed up to 3...
The GameObjects should be in while loop. Ball images sometimes (randomly), the balls should be retun own 360 degrees. And get picture on TectureRegion. 
Is there a similar example ? or
How can I do this ?

(Sorry for bad english)

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

As much as i understood you want your ball objects to move arround until you quit the game. Also you want to speed them up on touch right? Also you want to texture them and maybe they should detect collision with the screen borders and other balls to?

1. Libgdx has a main loop. This loop calls `render(delta)` every renderloop. The `delta` depends on the time ellapsed since last call of `render`. So on fast devices this `delta` is smaller then on slow devices (most times). This time is given in seconds. To move your objects you can add a value to their position in every render loop. In your case you want to add 1 (hopefully not pixel, as it then would seem slower on big screens):

   for(BallObject ball : ballObjects) {
        ball.setPositionX(ball.getPositionX() + ball.getSpeed() * delta * direction.x);
        ball.setPositionY(ball.getPositionY() + ball.getSpeed() * delta * direction.y);
   }

In this case a `BallObject` has a `positionX` and `positionY` describing his current position, a `direction.x` and `direction.y`, describing his movement in x and y direction (for 45° it would be direction.x=0.5 and direction.y=0.5), as well as a `speed` describing movement per second. This speed will be set to 3 on touch.

1. To speed the ball up on touch, you first need to implement `InputProcessor` in the class, which manages the movement of all ballobjects. Next you have to set it as the `InputProcessor` of the game: `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);`. The `InputProcessor` has a method `touchDown(int x, int y)` or something like that. The x and y value are giving the coordinates in pixels, on the screen.
   If you are using a camera or viewport in the new Libgdx version (you should do that) you have to use `camera.unproject(x,y)` or the `viewport` version of that (idk the exact method name). This method gives you the touchposition in your world coordinate system. Then you can simply check which ball is on this touchpos and set its speed to 3.
2. To texture the ball you have to use `SpriteBatch` for drawing. Look at the different `draw()` methods in the [API](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html) and use the one which fits best for you. Just load a `Texture`, which should be a ".png" with a circle texture and the rest of it should be transparent (alpha = 0). With blending enabled (default) it will then only render the ball, even if it is actually a rectangle shaped `Texture`.

I hope it helps